# QueryDSL integration with micrometer

Tags: querydsl, micrometer, spring-micrometer

We wanted to integrate queryDSL with micrometer.

I search for different solutions. However, haven't able to figure out how to get metrics of DB query execution time.

We could use `@Timed` annotations above the method but that will provide metrics for the execution time of the whole method.

In jooq we have a separate `DSLContext` for micrometer that will resolve this issue.
Is there anything for QueryDSL.